# python is showing a excel file that is not present in a folder

Tags: python

Basically i'm trying to print all excel files in a directory. In one of the folders, i don't have a excel file named '~$EndManifold-4Slot.xlsm', but while printing the files, i see this is present, which is actually not there.

Could anyone suggest on how to improve the same?

```
        def Fnfolders(rootdir):
            xlFilesList=[]
            for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rootdir):
                for file in os.listdir(dirname):
                    if '.xls' in file or '.xlsx' in file:
                        fullPath=os.path.join(dirname)+"\\"+file
                        xlFilesList.append(fullPath)
            return xlFilesList

        xlFilesList=Fnfolders(rootdir)
        for excel in xlFilesList:
            print (excel)
```

Comment: I tried renaming the excel file in that specific folder to some other name too, but still not successful. I opened task manager to see if anything is catching around. I don't see any files hanging there.

Comment: It is definitely present. Ensure you have enabled showing of hidden files in Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, files like - `~$EndManifold-4Slot.xlsm` are temporary files created when you openned your file in Excel. they are usually hidden, you can find them in your explorer if you enable [`Show Hidden Files` in folder options.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/show-hidden-files)

You can read more about those temporary files [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/211632) .