# pandas to_excel function writes a file with 0 bytes

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-excel

I use the following function to write a pandas DataFrame to Excel

```
def write_dataset(
    train: pd.DataFrame,
    forecast: pd.DataFrame,
    config
    out_path: str,
) -> None:
    
    forecast = forecast.rename(
        columns={
            "col": "col_predicted",
            }
    )
    df = pd.concat([train, forecast])
    df.drop(["id"], axis=1, inplace=True)
    if config.join_meta:
        df.drop(
            ["some_col", "some_other_col"],
            axis=1,
            inplace=True,
        )
    df.sort_values(config.id_columns, inplace=True)
    df.rename(columns={"date": "month"}, inplace=True)
    df["a_col"] = df["a_col"].round(2)
    df.to_excel(out_path, index=False)
```

just before the `df.to_excel()` the DataFrame looks completely normal, just containing some NaNs. But the file it writes is a 0 Byte file, which I can't even open with Excel. I use this function for 6 different dfs and somehow it works for some and doesn't for others. Also on my colleagues computer it always works fine.
I'm using python version 3.10.4, pandas 1.4.2 and opnepyxl 3.0.9
Any ideas what is happening and how to fix that behavior?

Comment: At first glance I don't see why this wouldn't work. I would try to first print the dataframe just to make sure that there is actually some data to save in the first place.

Comment: I actually did that. The df looks fine

Comment: Compare the versions (including that of openpyxl) with your colleagues computer.

Comment: we've both created a new environment from the same requirements.txt, so that we have the same versions. The only difference is that he has a Mac with an M1 chip and I have a Mac with an Intel chip...

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue on my Mac, and was similarly stumped for a while. Then I realized that the file appears as 0 bytes once the code has *begun* to create the file *but hasn't yet finished*.

So in my case, I found that all I had to do was wait a long time, and eventually (> 5-10m) the file jumped from 0 bytes to its full size. My file was about 14mb, so it shouldn't have required that much time. My guess is that this is an issue related to how the OS is handling scheduling and permissions among various processes and memory locations, hence why some dfs work fine and others don't.

(So it might be worth double checking that you don't have other processes that might be trying to claim write access of the write destination. I've seen programs like automatic backup services claim access to folders and cause conflicts along these lines.)

Comment: thanks Bryany, I had the same issue for some files but some remain at 0 bytes even after hours. The files are not massively big (~50mb) so I don't understand the issue